# Problems with making "Catch the falling hair" game

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know, this is a strange one. I'm trying to make a simple Javascript game where:

1. The player has to catch the randomly falling head hair.
2. The hair returns to the head when caught.
3. Catching the falling hair increases the Score
4. The hair falls faster and faster over time.
5. If all of the hair falls then it's GAME OVER.

I've given it a go, and copied most of it to my fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/pixering/9pq6xfxc/), which is an abstract version of what I'm trying to achieve.

Current Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    //randomize hair initial rotation
    $('.hair').each(function(){
        var random = Math.random()*360;
        var degree = "rotate("+random+"deg)";
        $(this).css("transform",degree);
    });

    //set points to 0
    $('#points').text(points);
});

function startGame() {
    start = true;
    var level = 1;

    //move catcher with hand
    $( document ).on("mousemove", function(event) {
        var catcherX = event.pageX - 50;
        $('#catcher').css("left",catcherX);
    });


    $('.hair').each(function() {
        var wait = Math.ceil(Math.random()*10000)/level;
        randomX = Math.random()*($('#gameDiv').width());

        function makeDestination(hair) {
            hair.css("top", 510);
            hair.css("left", randomX);
        }

        setTimeout(makeDestination($(this)), wait)
    })
};

startGame();
```

The biggest problems I'm having are:

1. How can I make the hair fall after a random interval? `wait` currently isn't doing anything in the `setTimout` function.
2. How can I make the hair function start again after being caught?

I also feel like there must be a much better way of writing this game, what do you guys think?

Comment: You're not using `setTimeout` properly. You need to pass it a function, not a call to a function – https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made the `setTimeout` reference the function instead of calling it immediately (putting the parens calls it and references the return value, putting just the function name references). Then I tweaked the transition to animate the `top` over 3 seconds while the `left` takes just 1 second. Then I made `makeDestination` call itself after a delay. Lastly, the "hair" needs to jump back up to the top, so I change the transition to be immediate, change the CSS, then change the transition back to animate.

https://jsfiddle.net/9pq6xfxc/1/

I leave it to you to detect the intersection of the cyan box and the hair. While this can obviously be done on mouse movement, it's going to be trickier to find the hairs that fall on a stationary hand.

Comment: Thanks, that's awesome! I've been wondering why I couldn't make the `setTimeout` work like on the tutorials @.@